# Are there issues with the Death Valley claim of 134 degrees?

Tags: discussion

Today NYT reports:

> "The W.M.O. assessment is that the highest recorded surface temperature of 56.7 degrees C (134 degrees F) was measured on 10 July 1913" in Death Valley, the report said.

But Mr. Burt said he had issues as well with the Death Valley claim of 134 degrees, and suspects it may be wrong. "It's anomalous, even for Death Valley."

Is there a claim here to investigate?

I'm wondering if I can ask on the main site.

Thank you.

Comment: I would question why this is a notable sceptical claim in the first place: it sounds plausible enough. Sure you can be sceptical of it but what does it matter? Is this particular datum of any further relevance? It sounds utterly mundane.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While there may be something to be skeptical about in this claim, I highly doubt that it would be answered to the standards of this site.  All we can really report is what the historical record shows us, and even though it may be anomalous, that doesn't make it impossible.  Anomalous weather happens quite often throughout the world.  Unless someone really has access to archived information that most users normally wouldn't (the instruments used in 1913, detailed records, etc.) you may find yourself frustrated.

Interesting question.  By the way, [there was a question about the Mount Washington wind speed record a while back, you may want to look at that one and see if you can perhaps frame your question to be in line with that one](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/1238/does-the-mount-washington-wind-speed-record-have-scientific-validity).